# Symfony serializer (v6.1.6) slow denormalize operation

Tags: php, performance, symfony, serialization

I am having a simple REST API developed with Symfony 6. I am using the following serializer for my application:

```
$encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
$extractor = new PropertyInfoExtractor([], [new PhpDocExtractor(), new ReflectionExtractor()]);
$responseNormalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, new CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter(),null, $extractor);
$dateTimeNormalizer = new DateTimeNormalizer([DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY => DateTimeType::DEFAULT_FORMAT]);
$arrayDenormalizer = new ArrayDenormalizer();
$normalizers = [$arrayDenormalizer, $dateTimeNormalizer, $responseNormalizer];
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

return $serializer->denormalize($data, $className);
```

I realized my response times are very slow and figured out that the `->denormalize()` call is the bottleneck. Even though these tests were made on local environment I noticed that when I make simple GET request for products, this returns 20 items per page (paginated response) and denormalize call for each of these 20 items takes around 300-400ms on average.

My question is, is there anything I am doing obviously wrong, a way to optimize my Serializer definition? I found in couple of posts that `ObjectNormalizer` is the problematic slow one but didn't manage to find any concrete solutions how to optimize it?

Comment: Without more information, it is difficult to accurately determine the cause of the issue. It may be more helpful to create a small reproducer application and report this issue on the Symfony repository.